# htaccess - using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I search a lot websites and lots of links and i follow the same for enable htacces in wamp but facing the problem and now as default use index.php even when i run the page without index.php its not working even msg comes page not found on server i already enable in apache module also the httpd.conf file remove the # sign from rewrite module and i use the mention below code in htaccess file for codeigniter for suggestions i share htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

please suggest so i can solve this issue on wamp server

Comment: did you restart the `WAMP` after making changes in `httpd.conf`

Comment: restart services also restart the pc too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_project_name/
# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: i already accepted :p msg comes again and again for 3 min wait thats why i wait :D

Comment: i have one more problem can you please see the code and suggest

Comment: than you have to post the new question As Per the Rule

Comment: i know :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109216/parse-error-in-controller-file) please check this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```