# parse error in controller file

Tags: php, codeigniter

i made a controller name of user.php i test complete project on local host it works fine but when i upload online on website it shows error , i submit the form then form load controller called user.php and error on the first line its called parse error i check but still the same will you please suggest.

```
<?php 

class User extends CI_Controller {

                function __construct()
                {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->helper('url');
                }

public function create_user()
            {
            // field name, error message, validation rules
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');     
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
            $this->load->view('ar_signup');
            }
            else
            {           
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            if($this->input->post("language")=="ar")
            {
            $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
            }
            else
            {
            $this->load->view('en_thanks');
            }
            if($query = $this->Users_model->create_member())
            {
            $this->load->view('ar_thanks');         
            }
                }               
                        }

    }
```

Comment: Specify detailed error

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is abou

Comment: @Formal you need to provide the detail information of error coming, Parse error is type of error but you have not specified that what is the error.

Comment: Adarsh i just get error in this file Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in, thats why i share complete code of file because i end the php and all curly bracket but still shows error.

Comment: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in ** this error coming web i submit form.

Comment: [link](http://giftotravel.pk/landingpage) online website link you can check form also.

Comment: you've missed a closing `}`. If you format your code correctly, you'd be able to see this.

Comment: @Prisoner i have checked this code..i have not found any missing `}` in his code.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code and use IDE. And you will not have these errors. Your formatted code:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function create_user()
    {
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('ar_signup');
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            if($this->input->post("language")=="ar") {
                $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
            } else {
                $this->load->view('en_thanks');
            }
            if($query = $this->Users_model->create_member()) {
                $this->load->view('ar_thanks');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as you mention the code i use the same but still same error i recv
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/gifto/public_html/landingpage/application/controllers/user.php on line 1, but this error when i upload file for online server i run this file on local server it works fine.